# Schedule AWS EC2 Spot instance Creation/Termination

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scheduled-tasks

Ive been finding my self creating(maintain)/terminating ec2 spot fleet every 12 hours due the application not needing to run full time. I would like the fleet to be created at 8am for example and terminated 8pm. Is this possible?

I can do this with ec2 instances +lambda + cloudwatch: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/

However I cannot seem to figure this out with spot fleet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an Autoscaling Group with a spot price, then use [Scheduled Actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/schedule_time.html#create-sch-actions-aws-cli) to launch and terminate them at specific times.